# How to have 2 Neo4j DB's on same computer: dev and test

Tags: neo4j

I'm using Neo4j with Node.js to build a REST API.

I'd like to write some tests for this API.  How do I use a "test database" during those tests?

With MySQL or MongoDB, I'd fiddle the resource URL to use a different database like "app-test" vs "app".

What's the smart way to do that in neo4j?

Thanks!

**SOLUTION: This is what I did:**

Made a directory db/test.  In that dir, put:

- two bash scripts below
- a test.zip with backup of the database you want

install.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

VERSION=neo4j-community-2.1.5

# Download a copy of the server
wget http://dist.neo4j.org/$VERSION-unix.tar.gz
# Unpack it here
tar -xvzf $VERSION-unix.tar.gz
# Change the default port to http->7475  https->7476
sed -i.bak s/7474/7475/g $VERSION/conf/neo4j-server.properties
sed -i.bak s/7473/7476/g $VERSION/conf/neo4j-server.properties
```

restart.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

VERSION=neo4j-community-2.1.5

echo === stop the server
$VERSION/bin/neo4j stop

echo --- replace the database
rm -rf $VERSION/data/graph.db
unzip -q test.zip -d $VERSION/data/graph.db

echo --- start the server
$VERSION/bin/neo4j start
```

Then added it to gruntfile using grunt-run:

```
run: {
  restartTestDb: {
    exec: 'cd db/test && ./restart.sh',
  }
},
```

Works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same thing with neo4j. Just install another copy of neo4j in a separate location, and [configure it to use a different port](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-configuration.html#_important_server_configurations_parameters).

After each test, you can delete the `graph.db` file to clear all the data.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently busy with a project that can manage and switch databases from the command line.

I'm busy with fixing the neo4j download feature, this is still in WIP but the more users, the more quickly stable it can be.

I should push on github within an hour or two.

EDIT: Repository here https://github.com/neoxygen/neo4j-toolkit

Live video here http://recordit.co/YRVhOJKXdj